# Web Part alignment query

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, formatting

How do I align the content editor web part in the right column to match the same height as the script editor web part in the left column? I've tried fixed sizes in the web part properties but that doesn't help!

[image]

Comment: You could try with jquery match height plugin: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

Comment: unsure how Id implement this on SharePoint.

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of both of these and replace them with a single content-editor webpart? In this case you will have full control of your HTML? You can also check out [CSS flex boxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) It's amazing for solving tasks like yours.

Comment: I wanted two boxes with different headers as I do in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the content editor web part and select "Yes" for the option "Should the Web Part have a fixed height". Then change the value to fix your purpose. Click "Apply" to check the result after each time you change the value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you think my suggestion is helpful, you could mark it as an answer.